# Trying to set a channel and message environment variable globally in a Jenkinsfile but not sure which of two methods are best

Tags: groovy, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Trying to make **SEND_SLACK_NOTIF, SLACK_CHANNEL** and **SLACK_MESSAGE** variables and set them as environment variables globally in Jenkins file but I'm not sure which method is superior in a multi-stage pipeline. Don't mind the indenting!

Method 1:

```
 #!/usr/bin/groovy

    node('large') {

    withEnv(['SEND_SLACK_NOTIF=true',
            'SLACK_CHANNEL=UT24K22K1',
            "SLACK_MESSAGE=FAILURE: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'\nBetter fix it! (${env.BUILD_URL})"]){
        stage('Test') {
            if (env.SEND_SLACK_NOTIF) {
                slackSend channel: env.SLACK_CHANNEL, color: 'danger', message: env.SLACK_MESSAGE, tokenCredentialId: 'slack-integration-token'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Method 2:

```
 #!/usr/bin/groovy
    env.SEND_SLACK_NOTIF = true
    env.SLACK_CHANNEL = 'UT24K22K1'
    env.SLACK_MESSAGE = "FAILURE: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'\nBetter fix it! (${env.BUILD_URL})"

node('large') {

stage('Test') {
            if (env.SEND_SLACK_NOTIF) {
                slackSend channel: env.SLACK_CHANNEL, color: 'danger', message: env.SLACK_MESSAGE, tokenCredentialId: 'slack-integration-token'
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just consider your two options, I'd go with option 1 because it's more declarative than option 2. However the superior way is the one described in the [Jenkins documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/):

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        ...
    }

    environment {
        SEND_SLACK_NOTIF = 'true'
        SLACK_CHANNEL = 'UT24K22K1'
    }

    stages {
        ...
    }
}
```

You might also want to reconsider which variables you really need. If you only use them once, don't use a variable, but use the value directly.